# nested resource only working on edit not new, rails 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-resources

I have the following resources defined:

```
resources :buildings do
  resources :buildings_regular_hours
end
```

My models are are follows:

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :building_regular_hours

  def to_s
    name
  end
end

class BuildingsRegularHours < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
end
```

I am attempting to create a form to allow for creating and editing of `BuildingRegularHours`. Currently the form I have will display on `#edit`, but will not display on `#new`.

new.html.erb:

```
<%= render 'form', buildings_regular_hour: @buildings_regular_hour, building: @building %>
```

edit.html.erb:

```
<h1>Editing Buildings Regular Hour</h1>

<%= render 'form', buildings_regular_hour: @buildings_regular_hour, building: @building %>

<%= link_to 'Back', building_buildings_regular_hour_path(@building) %>
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for([building,buildings_regular_hour]) do |f| %>
  <% if buildings_regular_hour.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(buildings_regular_hour.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this buildings_regular_hour from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% buildings_regular_hour.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :building_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :building_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end_date %>
    <%= f.date_select :end_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

buildings_regular_hours_controller.rb:

```
class BuildingsRegularHoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_buildings_regular_hour, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_building

  # GET /buildings_regular_hours
  # GET /buildings_regular_hours.json
  def index
    @buildings_regular_hours = BuildingsRegularHours.all
  end

  # GET /buildings_regular_hours/1
  # GET /buildings_regular_hours/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /buildings_regular_hours/new
  def new
    @buildings_regular_hour = BuildingsRegularHours.new
  end

  # GET /buildings_regular_hours/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /buildings_regular_hours
  # POST /buildings_regular_hours.json
  def create
    @buildings_regular_hour = BuildingsRegularHours.new(buildings_regular_hour_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @buildings_regular_hour.save
        format.html { redirect_to @buildings_regular_hour, notice: 'Buildings regular hours was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @buildings_regular_hour }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @buildings_regular_hour.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /buildings_regular_hours/1
  # PATCH/PUT /buildings_regular_hours/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @buildings_regular_hour.update(buildings_regular_hour_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @buildings_regular_hour, notice: 'Buildings regular hours was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @buildings_regular_hour }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @buildings_regular_hour.errors,     status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /buildings_regular_hours/1
  # DELETE /buildings_regular_hours/1.json
  def destroy
    @buildings_regular_hour.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to buildings_regular_hours_index_url, notice: 'Buildings regular hours was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_buildings_regular_hour
      @buildings_regular_hour = BuildingsRegularHours.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_building
      @building = Building.find(params[:building_id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def buildings_regular_hour_params
      params.require(:buildings_regular_hour).permit(:building_id, :start_date, :end_date, :sunday_id, :monday_id, :tuesday_id, :wednesday_id, :thursday_id, :friday_id, :saturday_id)
    end
end
```

Having added a `BuildingRegularHours` via console, I attempted the `#edit` action, and it works just fine, displaying the form as expected. However, when I attempt the `#new` action, I receive the following error:

```
Showing /Users/shawn/Documents/uga/library_hours/app/views/buildings_regular_hours/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `building_buildings_regular_hours_index_path` for #<#<Class:0x007fe9589e2890>:0x007fe95f9bbb30>
Did you mean?  building_buildings_regular_hours_path
               building_buildings_regular_hour_path
               building_buildings_regular_hours_url
               building_buildings_regular_hour_url
Extracted source (around line #1):
1 <%= form_for([building,buildings_regular_hour]) do |f| %>
2   <% if buildings_regular_hour.errors.any? %>
3     <div id="error_explanation">
4       <h2><%= pluralize(buildings_regular_hour.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this buildings_regular_hour from being saved:</h2>
5
6       <ul>
Trace of template inclusion:         app/views/buildings_regular_hours/new.html.erb
```

I note that I have properly nested the resources in the `form_for` tag, that both `@building` and `@building_regular_hour` are set by the controller, and that I am calling the form in exactly the same way for both `#edit` and `#new`. This is all I've had to do previously to make nested resources work, so I'm at a bit of a loss as what to do next.

Please note I have not attempted to make the form work yet - I know there is work to be done there. I just am trying to get `#new` to display the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct the association

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :buildings_regular_hours

  def to_s
    name
  end
end

class BuildingsRegularHour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
end
```

Your model name should always be singular `BuildingsRegularHour` or it will create issues with routes and associations

Comment: Changing the model name and renaming the model file did not do the trick, but I'm still not certain that this is not the answer. I'm going to start clean, since I'm early enough in development, and not use plurals.

Comment: just go through rails guides once

Comment: Reading the guides for half an hour will save hours of debugging for you

Comment: I've read the guides and understand them. I've deployed Rails apps with nested resources before. I just never tried to use models generated with the --force-plurals option, which is probably the problem. I used the --force-plurals option to try and get more meaningful model names, since I'm modeling a set of hours; calling them hour was inelegant and I thought you could override the plurals option cleanly. Clearly not. Thanks for assuming I have zero knowledge.

Comment: In a brand new instance, without forcing plurals, my implementation works. So you were correct that plurals were the problem. Makes me wonder why there is a --force-plurals option to the generators.